# Installing ClojureScript with Lein

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there a way to install ClojureScript via

"lein install ... " ?

Two sources I've found googling for clojurescript both seem to pull from git:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start

http://clojurescriptone.com/getting-started.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a leiningen plugin called lein-cljsbuild at https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild.

See the documentation at the link, but essentially, you will add it as a plugin, then add some configuration in project.clj to let it know where your source and build directories are.

Comment: The links to documentation at this site are no longer valid.

Comment: Filed an [issue](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/issues/275), in the meantime, you can find the documentation in the doc directory of the project.